# How can I create a custom metric based on specific event in Google Data Studio?

Tags: looker-studio

I am trying to make a custom metric in Google Data Studio to show the [`SUM`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583212) of a metric (`Unique Events`) for a specific dimension (`Event category`) and string ("*Contact Us*") for the date range 01 Aug 2022 to 03 Aug 2022, but it keeps just returning the value of 1 when I add it to a scorecard.

I would like to avoid using a component filter or a blend to achieve this, as I will expand it's use and require the component filter to be free in future.

The formula I am using is:

```
SUM(case when REGEXP_MATCH(Event category, "Contact Us") then 1 else 0 end)
```

The correct data in tabular form and the scorecard on the right is showing the incorrect value:

[image: report]

**Data set**

I am using universal analytics demo data for purposes of demonstration.

Here is the data set in tabular form, the event I want to focus on is "*Contact Us*"

| Date | Event Category | Unique Events | Total Events |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Aug 3, 2022 | Enhanced Ecommerce | 1043 | 2037 |
| Aug 2, 2022 | Enhanced Ecommerce | 1021 | 1882 |
| Aug 1, 2022 | Enhanced Ecommerce | 1023 | 1943 |
| Aug 3, 2022 | Contact Us | 9 | 14 |
| Aug 2, 2022 | Contact Us | 12 | 43 |
| Aug 1, 2022 | Contact Us | 13 | 21 |

I have made a sample [Google Data Studio](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/2f3c9a60-e99c-4864-b746-66e3ebdc497f) report available at which demonstrates the formula on the scorecard.

**Result Expected to show on scorecard:**

Resulting scorecard showing: 1

Scorecard expected to show: 34

In table form if using my formula I'd expect the data outputted to be as follows:

| Date | Event Category | Unique Events |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Aug 3, 2022 | Contact Us | 9 |
| Aug 2, 2022 | Contact Us | 12 |
| Aug 1, 2022 | Contact Us | 13 |

Comment: I don't think you will be able to do that kind of filtering within the formula for a metric. Within the formulas you cannot mix dimensions and metrics in the same statement. So you won't ever be able to say "Sum all the events for only [a]". I think this functionality is reserved for filters which are more easily managed than a custom field/formula. When I try to mix both dimensions and metrics, I am met with this: Sorry, calculated fields can't mix metrics (aggregated values) and dimensions (non-aggregated values). Please check the aggregation types of the fields used in this formula.

Comment: I event tried something like this: SUM(IF(REGEXP_MATCH(Event Category,"Contact US"),Unique Events,0))

Comment: your formula `SUM(case when REGEXP_MATCH(Event category, "Contact Us") then 1 else 0 end)` always returns 1, because there is one time the category. Adding the field `Event category` to a scorecard with aggregation sum and a filter on `Event Category` equal "Contact Us" will do the job. Please tell why you do not want filters or blends. What are your next steps?

Comment: @Samuel i was trying this approach as eventually i want to use these metrics as steps in a funnel, and ill only be able to add 1 filter to the funnel